# End tag li implied, but there were open elements

Tags: html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="h">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutus.html" class="h">About us</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#" class="h">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="h">Contacts</a></li>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hey there, I have this navbar code on my HTML project. However, when i insert my .html into validator.w3.org, i get the [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTXmo.png). Can someone please help me check? I'm pretty sure I closed it already..

Comment: Have you tried opening a new <ul> inside the <a> tag?

Comment: Sorry, can I get an example ? I don't quite understand what you meant..

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap those li tags inside anchor tag with ul.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="h">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutus.html" class="h">About us</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#" class="h">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="h">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

this will solve first warning in validator.

Comment: thank you !! :) now i just need to solve the <a> one :-(

Comment: You can not have an <a>-tag within an <a>-tag. So you have to remove the surrounding <aclass="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> or change it to another tag

Comment: For <a> you cant use nesting. Means <a> inside <a> is not permitted. You have to change your code accordingly

Comment: Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements.

[Nested Links are illegal](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

that is why you are getting warning.

Comment: thank you guys so much !! :) have finally cleared it by removing the whole <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> and the last </li>

Comment: Li is a block level element and so is ul tag. A is an inline element. Inline elements should only contain inline elements. If you want to wrap block level elements inside the equivalent of a link, then use javascript onclick event instead. 

Using javascript will then require more validation requirements for wcag so then you will need to add a role and follow best practice for that too.